# What did the title "A Memory of Light" refer to?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, behind-the-scenes, a-memory-of-light

One of the things that Robert Jordan left after his untimely death was the title of the final book of the Wheel of Time - *A Memory of Light*.

Of course, this final book became the "Sanderson Trilogy":

- The Gathering Storm
- Towers of Midnight
- A Memory of Light

What was the meaning behind the title *A Memory of Light*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In *A Memory of Light* when Rand is battling the Dark One,

> he lists off all the people who still fight the Shadow.

It is this "Memory of Light" that prevents the Dark One from

> breaking Rand.

And indeed it's said that

> the Dark One can't win while people still have hope, so a "Memory of Light" would be enough to prevent the Dark One's victory.

Comment: +1 just for your name. And for being right, but mainly the name. :-)